# TFS 2010 prerequisites

Tags: tfs

1)Can Any one please tell me what are the prerequisites have been installed on the machine.

2)Is sqlserver 2008 enterprise trial edition compatible with TFS?.

I try to install the this sqlserver but ended with exception
 ".net framework3.5 is required".
But I have the .netframework 3.5 sp1 installed already.

For this when I search on web many suggested to install "windows installer 4.5".
But when I try to install it its giving error like "not enough memory available to complete this operation"...
Even I try to fix it by addding registry key called IRPStackSize   with values like 15,25,30...
none of worked.

Please answer me I'm stuck in TFS configuration due to lack of software installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect to :

http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=15070

Firstly download  Iso, when you install Iso, if sql server is not installed in your PC,,, Iso launch installation

Comment: I installed basic version of tfs,and connected to tfs from visual studio. But when I try to go online from solution explorer its giving error saying "unable to determine workspace". Pls tell me what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can decompress Iso file with Daemon Tools, you must download, and you click mount and select the iso file. the installation take severals minutes

Answer (score 0):

You must create workspace, follow this steps :

1. Open Team  Explorer
2. Click on Source Control, select dropdownlist of workspace (top of screen)
3. Create your workspace (Name, PC, owner....)
4. Synchronize your source control in tfs with workspace (Check that workspace is selected in drop down list).
5. You can get latest version in your workspace

Comment: In order to select workspace, 1. you can also select File in visual studio. 2. select Source control item 3. select workspaces item